# It has at most one absorbing element

Tags: abstract-algebra, universal-algebra

Let $G = (M, \circ )$ be a  groupoid and let $2^G = (2^M, \circ_K)$ a  groupoid

( $\circ_K$ is the Product of group subsets).

How can show that $G$ has at most one absorbing element?

Comment: When you say "groupoid" here do you mean "magma"?

Comment: Yes. @QiaochuYuan

Comment: Then $2^G$ is totally irrelevant to this question. - Hint: multiply two absorbing elements.

Comment: So, do we do the following? $$$$ We suppose that there are two absorbing elements, let $z_1,z_2$. Then $z_1=z_1\circ z_2=z_2$. So, there is at most one absorbing element. @HagenvonEitzen